# CollapsingToolbarLayout design failure

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, toolbar

I am creating an CollapsingToolbarLayout and it should look like this:

[image]

But it has this ugly blue "thing" under it:
[image]

And here is the XML (It's in a coordinatorlayout, but it gets cut away.):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_view_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_image"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Info"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="test" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>





    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

What could be the error? I also tried a vertical image. Thank you!

Comment: Did you tried to delete `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` attribute from your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` ?

Comment: Did you place the CollapsingToolbarLayout inside an AppBarLayout?

Comment: @Yasin Kaçmaz yes, I have tried it.

Comment: @Robbe Yes, I have.

Comment: @user6586661 I had issue like in your image. Can you post your RecyclerView xml code too ?

Comment: @user6586661 I post an answer by looking my last commit. Can you try to take reference it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a layout like you, can you try with this layout structure , I think adding `android:layout_below="@+id/profileactivity_appbar"` was fixed my problem

Also you have no scroll flags in your `Toolbar`

Another thing I see; make sure your transition transforms image correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profileCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/profileactivity_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme3.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileactivity_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/ColorPrimaryDark"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileactivity_fullimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profile_recyclerview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profileactivity_appbar"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```